# Tomcat does not pick up the class file - the JSP file is not displayed

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have a Java code which is a controller for a jsp page, called: HomeController.java. Code  is as follows:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    protected final transient Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @RequestMapping(value = "/mypage")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("HomeController: Passing through...");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

There is nothing especial in the jsp page: home.jsp. If I go to this url:

http://localhost:8080/adcopyqueue/mypage

I can view mypage and everything works fine. Also in the tomcat Dos page I can see the comment:

```
HomeController: Passing through...
```

As expected.

Now under the same directory that I have HomeController.java, I've created another file called: LoginController.java. Following is the code:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    protected final transient Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginpage")
    public String login() {
        System.out.println("LoginController: Passing through...");        
        return "login";
    }
}
```

And under the same place which I have home.jsp, I've created login.jsp.

Also under tomcat folders, LoginController.class exists under the same folder that HomeController.class exists and login.jsp exists under the same folder which home.jsp exists.

But when I go to this url: http://localhost:8080/adcopyqueue/loginpage

Nothing is displayed! I think tomcat does not pick up LoginController.class b/c on the tomcat Dos window, I do NOT see this comment:

```
LoginController: Passing through...
```

Instead I see following which I do not know what do they mean?

```
[ INFO] [http-8080-1 01:43:45] (AppInfo.java:populateAppInfo:34) got manifest
[ INFO] [http-8080-1 01:43:45] (AppInfo.java:populateAppInfo:36) manifest entrie
s 8
```

The structure and the code for HomeController.java and LoginController.java plus the jsp files match. I have no idea why tomcat sees one of the files and not the other?

Clean build did not help. Does anybody have any idea? Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is part of web.xml: config file:

```
<servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name> <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>               </servlet-mapping> <filter-mapping> <filter-name>rewriteFilter</filter-name> <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </filter-mapping> –
```

Just discovered:
I modified the return value of method in LoginController from:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
```

To following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myLastName")
```

And it just worked! The web page is seen as expected and in Tomcat Dos window, now I see this comment:

LoginController: Passing through...

I did suspect the naming before and had tried with "login", "loginpage" and "loginpage1" and none had worked! Have no idea why its happening! It has a problem with any name with the word "login" in it! Eventually it should work with "login" though!!!

One more thing which I just noticed:
The LoginController will NOT work as long as the value="/ any name that starts with login"

So for ex. login, loginpage, ... will not work. However, pagelogin works, meaning the name should not start with the word: login.

Comment: Can you post any relevant snippet from the web.xml?

Comment: Here is web.xml, not sure if it help though... <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>rewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

Comment: <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>rewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

Comment: I assume the servlet *spring* is a `DispatcherServlet`. From the snippet, it appears that the *spring* servlet would only process requests like `http://<host>/<context>/app/...`. If that's the case, the home controller should not be invoked either. Please check if you have other mappings, and if so, they are mapped properly.

Comment: That's true... however, I do see the webpage for HomeController which is home.jsp. All other web pages appear in this form: http://localhost:8080/adcopyqueue/<rest of address> like: http://localhost:8080/adcopyqueue/mypage Honestly I do not know the reason!

Comment: How you guys use the Enter key to go to the next line? As soon as I hit Enter, it posts the comment!

Comment: Please put the addition config info in the question, not in comments. Thanks!

Comment: I added config and extra comments including a temp solution in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was the reason... answered by my manager... maybe it helps somebody in the future :-)

In the urlrewrite.xml, there was rules set for:

```
<!-- Add rules here for anything that shouldn't be served up by Spring MVC. -->
```

So we commented the following lines to skip the rule:

```
<rule>
    <from>/login*</from>
    <to>/login.jsp</to>
</rule>
<rule>
    <from>/logout*</from>
    <to>/logout.jsp</to>
</rule>
```